# Reflective and Constant Flux Boundary Conditions

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, finite-element-method, heat-equation

Can anyone tell me how I can use `NDSolveValue` to model reflective and constant heat flux boundary conditions. I am solving the heat equation. Essentially I have a PDE that is dependent on time, radius, and axial length. I want to solve it such that the spatial derivative of the temperature is equal to 0 on one boundary and equal to a constant on another boundary. Can anyone explain how I can set up `NDSolveValue` with these types of boundary conditions? I don't think it can be achieved using [`NeumannValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html) because that just sets the entire differential equation to a value. I have tried a lot of different approaches but nothing seems to be working for me. Can anyone please recommend a way to achieve this?

Edit: Here is some code

```
tf = 50; Ti = 100; 
Ls =  250; Lito = 5;  Lsl = 230;
Ltot = Ls + Lito + Lsl;
R = 1500; k = 1; 

eqn = r*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(t\)]\(T[t, r, z]\)\) - r*k*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(z, z\)]\(T[t, r, z]\)\) - k*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(r\)]\(T[t, r, z]\)\) - k*r*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(r, r\)]\(T[t, r, z]\)\);
Subscript[Γ, D] = {DirichletCondition[T[t, r, z] == Ti, z == Ltot], 
   DirichletCondition[T[t, r, z] == Ti, r == R]};

BCr = NDSolveValue[{eqn == 0, Subscript[Γ, D], \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(r\)]\(T[t, 0, z]\)\) == 0, \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(z\)]\(T[t, r, 0]\)\) == -100, 
    T[0, r, z] == Ti}, T, {t, 0, tf}, {r, 0, R}, {z, 0, Ltot}];
```

Comment: Can you add a simple example (code) and an example of what you expect?

Comment: I encourage you to become a regular contributor to Mathematica.SE..  To do so effectively,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `v[x, t]` the dependent variable, and `x` the spatial independent variable ranging from `x1` to `x2`, the requested boundary conditions are,

```
v[x1, t] == 0
(D[v[x, t], x] /. x -> x2) == 0
```

In answer to the OP's comment below, these and any other boundary and initial conditions are included in the first argument of `NDSolveValue`, as illustrated by several of the Basic Examples in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html).

**Edit**

As noted in my comment below, the question's recently added code can be made to work with the change,

```
r0 = .1;
BCr = NDSolveValue[{eqn == 0, Subscript[Γ, D], (D[T[t, r, z], z] /. z -> 0) == 0, 
    (D[T[t, r, z], r] /. r -> r0) == 0, T[0, r, z] == Ti}, T, {t, 0, tf}, 
    {r, r0, R}, {z, 0, Ltot}]
```

For the parameters chosen in the question, `BCr` is equal to `Ti` everywhere.

Comment: I am assuming this code is independent of the NDSolveValue function. As in this code would be prior to the NDSolveValue function such that the boundary conditions are evaluated prior to solving.

Comment: @dowlguest  Please see the additional sentence that I added to my answer.

Comment: I have tried this method in the past and I get an  error message that says: `NDSolveValue::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument` where it is equating the differential boundary conditions equal to `True` instead of as a boundary condition. I have added code to the original question. This was the first method I tried.

Comment: @dowlguest  Try using the recommendation in  my earlier answer:  `(D[T[t, r, z], r] /. r -> 0) == 0`, `(D[T[t, r, z], z] /. z -> 0) == 0`.  However, you then will receive `Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>`, because the PDE is singular at `r = 0`.  To solve that problem, use some small number, say `r0 = 0.1` as the inner boundary condition on `r`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code you suggested works for reflective conditions but when I add a constant heat flux at the boundary I get another error. I am trying to have a constant heat flux when z=0 and I get the following error: `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. >>` All I did was change the code such that `(D[T[t, r, z], z] /. z -> 0) == -100`. Any suggestions for eliminating this error?

Comment: Another quick question. What does the `/.` represent in this code?

Comment: `/.` means replace; see the documentation for `Rule`.  In this case, it is necessary first to perform derivatives and only then to specify that the derivatives have been performed at the boundaries.  Doing these two steps in the opposite order fails.